# inverse laplace transform of this equation.

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform

I want to know how to find the inverse laplace transform of this function:

$$Y(s)=\frac {1}{\tau s+1}\times \frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}$$

for $\omega$, $\tau$ constant

Comment: What are $\tau$, $\omega$, and $s$? What have you tried?

Comment: um.. that's contants. and s is laplace... um. oh sorry, that Y(s) is fall in.

Comment: Well it would be if you don't know what all the variables stand for and what you are trying to do with them

Comment: Y(s)=1/(τs+1) ×ω/(s^ 2 +ω^ 2 ), this needs  to be solved... w, τ are constants.

Comment: Can you try this...?

Answer (score 0):

you can apply convolution theorem

and seperate laplace transform of them are 
$$\frac {1}{\tau s+1}\times \frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}$$
laplace for 1st is $$g(t)=\frac {1}{\tau}\exp{\frac {-t}{\tau}}$$
and for $$\frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}$$ is $$f(t)=\sin{\omega}{t}$$
hence apply convolution theorem $$\int_0^tg(v)f(t-v)\mathrm dv$$ solve the integral you get the result

Answer (score 0):

$$
y(x)=\frac{e^{-x/\tau} \omega \tau - \omega\tau\cos(\omega x) + \sin(\omega x)}{1+\omega^2\tau^2}
$$